# How to depict table joins in diagram?

Tags: database, diagram

I have several tables (let's call them `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc.), where each has multiple columns (`A` has columns `a1`, `a2`, etc.).

I'd like to diagrammatically represent the following:

Inner join `A` and `B` where `A.a1 = B.b1`, then check the value of `B.b2`. If `B.b2 = 1`, inner join the result with `C` where `A.a1 = C.c1`. If `B.b2 = 2`, inner join the result with `D` where `A.a1 = D.d1`.

I've tried to use a traditional flowchart, but I'd like to keep track of the tables and their columns. With a database schema diagram, however, I'm not sure how to depict things like logical conditions.

What's the best way to do this?